# Ubuntu 16.04 gtkspell

Tags: apt, package-management, python

This question is actually part of  [Virtaal check spell feature not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851500/virtaal-check-spell-feature-not-working).
How could I install gtkspell and resolve this error:

```
ERROR:root:Failed to load plugin "spellchecker"
No module named gtkspell
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtaal/controllers/plugincontroller.py", line 109, in    enable_plugin
        self.plugins[name] = plugin_class(name, self.controller)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtaal/plugins/spellchecker.py", line 69, in __init__
        import gtkspell
ImportError: No module named gtkspell
```

I have downloaded source from here http://gtkspell.sourceforge.net compiled and installed it, but doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module was renamed `gtkspellcheck` since Ubuntu Xenial. The API has changed too. See the new API here: [Python GTK Spellchecker (readthedocs.io)](https://pygtkspellcheck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).